# Service zfs-import is masked and unmask does not help Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: automount, 19.10, zfs

I read the information about how to make ZFS autoimport my zpools after reboot. The instruction was to enable zfs.target zfs-import.service and zfs-mount service. However zfs-import.service report that it is masked and running unmask does not solve the problem. The machine is clean installed with the experimental ZFS support.

```
hakan@ubuhost:~$ sudo systemctl enable zfs-import.service
Synchronizing state of zfs-import.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable zfs-import
Failed to enable unit: Unit file /lib/systemd/system/zfs-import.service is masked.

hakan@ubuhost:~$ sudo systemctl unmask zfs-import.service

hakan@ubuhost:~$ sudo systemctl enable zfs-import.service
Synchronizing state of zfs-import.service with SysV service script with /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install.
Executing: /lib/systemd/systemd-sysv-install enable zfs-import
Failed to enable unit: Unit file /lib/systemd/system/zfs-import.service is masked.

hakan@ubuhost:~$ sudo systemctl status zfs-import.service
● zfs-import.service
   Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit zfs-import.service is masked.)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

The other two services enable without issues but without zfs-import it doesn't help much.

Answer (score 1):

From tags I see that you are using Ubuntu 19.10 and so as I. From `/etc/default/zfs`, we can learn that `zfs` in 19.10 does not use  `zpool.conf` to make pools persistent between reboots.

In [this](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ZFS) great documentation I learned about ZED service.
To make your pool automount you should:

import your pool

```
# systemctl enable zfs-zed.service
# systemctl enable zfs.target
# systemctl start zfs-zed.service
```

You need to create an empty file named after your pool in `/etc/zfs/zfs-list.cache` directory

If it is empty then check that `zfs-zed.service` is running and do:

```
zfs set canmount=off my-pool
zfs set canmount=off my-pool
```

And do not forget to `chown`/`chmod` your mount directory for non-superuser usage

Comment: FWIW the above instructions are incomplete. Definitely do go to source link and read through them there. Also, the source instructions work even though the toggling the ZFS `canmount`property has no effect on the zpool empty file. After completing the instructions, shut down and then turn on the PC. Your filesystems should mount.

Comment: how is that not completely unnecessary and instead something users are expected to manually maintain? what part of "computing" did you wrote here?

Comment: you want to `canmount=off` then `canmount=on` ... this is a ritual to wake up zed.